# Javascript operator precedence technicality

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time understanding what is meant by the combination of Exponentiation and everything else (Multiplication, Division, etc) in group 14 of the Javascript precedence.

**[Source - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)**

Three questions:

1. What is the meaning of combining the right-to-left and left-to-right associativity in one group?
2. How can the expression 2 ** 3 * 4 be rephrased according to these rules, and still get the same answer?  4 * 2 ** 3 works...is that what's meant?
3. When / how is this not equivalent to the seemingly simpler expedient of giving exponentiation higher precedence?

Comment: right to left means 2 ** 3 ** 4 =  Math.pow(2, Math.pow(3, 4));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `2 ** 3 ** 4`, being right-to-left associative, is `2 ** (3 ** 4)`. `2 / 3 / 4`, being left-to-right associative, is `(2 / 3) / 4`.

2/3) I believe `2 ** 3 * 4` is `(2 ** 3) * 4`. `2 * 3 ** 4` is `2 * (3 ** 4)` (as evaluated by [es6fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/)).

This does not follow from the table; but exponentiation should have precedence over multiplication. Mixing left-to-right and right-to-left in one precedence rank is strange. In fact, as far as I could see in [ES7 drafts](http://rwaldron.github.io/exponentiation-operator/), it is not at all treated grammatically the same way as `*`, `/` and `%`, but as a unary operation (!).

Also note that no engines other than Babel and Traceur have support for `**` at the current time, so it is mostly academic at this point. MDN is a wiki, and exponentiation operator was added by a Mozillian; but AFAIK since Mozilla doesn't currently support `**`, it does not actually document the way Mozilla interprets the language.

Comment: Thank you!  I somehow failed to grokk that exponentiation was experimental...I guess I internalized it as an essential back in the bad old days -- I think it's in FORTRAN :)

Comment: Exponentiation is kind of essential; but you have `Math.pow`. `**` is just syntactic sugar.